# Span aligning to bottom of facebook block. How to align to top?

Tags: html, css

I have this piece of code where I am trying to put some text content next to a Facebook page plugin. I am using this code but my content is aligning itself to the bottom of the facebook page plugin. How do I get it to align to the top instead?

```
    <span style="display:inline;">Some content here</span>

    <span style="display:inline;"><div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/page" data-width="400" data-height="500" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true"></div></span>
```

It appears like this:

[image: span]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two columns that are both wrapped with a parent div.  Then you just just float each column to their respective side.  Example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0716qjak/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="align-left">
        <span>Some content here</span>
    </div>

    <div class="align-right">
        <div class="fb"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
//you can ignore the .fb css class, it's just for the example
.fb {
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
}

.wrapper {
    height:500px;
    width: 400px;
}

.align-left {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;   
}

.align-right {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
}
```